# Is this approach correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, polar-coordinates, partial-fractions

I solved an ellipse-related problem with a polar coordinate transformation and wondered if the following calculation is possible.
$$\begin{align}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\frac{a^2b^2}{b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta}d\theta &=\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{a^2b^2\sec^2\theta}{b^2+a^2\tan^2\theta}d\theta \ \ (tan\theta \longmapsto t)\\ & =\frac{a^2b^2}{2}\int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{b^2+a^2t^2}\\ & = \frac{a^2b}{4}\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{b+ati}+\frac{1}{b-ati}\ dt =\frac{ab}{4i}\log{\frac{b+ati}{b-ati}}\left.\right|_{t=1}^{t\to\infty}\\ & =\frac{ab}{4i}\cdot i\tan^{-1}\frac{2ab}{a^2-b^2} \\ & =\frac{ab}{4}\tan^{-1}\frac{2ab}{a^2-b^2}\end{align}$$

During the process, $$\log \frac{b+ati}{b-ati} $$ can be calculated because
$$\frac{b+ati}{b-ati}=\frac{b^2-a^2t^2+2abi}{b^2+a^2t^2}=e^{i\tan^{-1} \frac{2abt}{b^2-a^2t^2}}$$

Comment: You **can** do it here, but one cannot advise it in general because 1) logarithm with complex argument is defined with a $+k2\pi i$ (here you are fortunate because $k=0$) 2)  It will not be accepted as a proof by your prof , for this reason, until you have lectures on complex function theory (then, you will understand the exact meaning of this strange function $Z=\log(z)$ which is even more important than its real counterpart $y=\ln(x)$

Comment: $a^2 b^2/2$ should be just $a^2 b^2$. You can verify by differentiation that both $-i \ln$ and $\tan^{-1}$ are antiderivatives of your integrand. If you choose a branch making the antiderivative continuous on $[1, \infty)$, then the fundamental theorem of calculus applies. Note that if your $\tan^{-1}$ is the usual $\tan^{-1}$ on the real line, then a) you need the assumption $a > b$ in your answer, and b) $i \tan^{-1}$ is not a branch of $\ln$ (consider that the lhs of your last equation tends to $-1$ and the rhs to $1$ when $t \to \infty$).